# How to merge two lists with different dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have two list, just like

```
a={a1,a2,a3,a4};
b={b1,b2,b3,b4,b5};
```

I want merge them and save to excel, as they have different dimention, so I want it have the following format.

```
{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3},{a4,b4},{null,b5}}
```

and in the excel it will leave blank or fill some special words in the miss information position.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) + [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight):

```
Transpose @ PadRight[{a,b}, Automatic, Null]
```

> {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {a4, b4}, {Null, b5}}